# unable to send binary data over unix tcp socket

Tags: c, unix, tcpsocket

I'm trying to implement ftp commands GET and PUT thru a UNIX socket for file transfer using usual functions like fread(), fwrite(), send() and recv().

It works fine for text files, but fails for binary files (diff says: "binary files differ")

Any suggestions regarding the following will be appreciated:

1. Are there any specific commands to read and write binary data?
2. Can diff be used to compare binary files?
3. Is it possible to send the binary parts in chunks of memory?

Answer (score 3):

the FTP protocol has 2 modes of operation: text and binary.
try it in any FTP client -- I believe the commands for switching in between are ASCII and BIN. The text mode has only effect from what I recall on the CR/LF pairs though.

Comment: i'm simulating the behavior of FTP using the unix TCP socket, therefore i want to know is there any way in which binary files can be transferred over a simple unix socket

Comment: @abcdxyz You have to tell the FTP server which mode you want the file sent/received in, either text or binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from a file and then writing the file's data to the socket, make sure you open the **file** in binary mode.

Yes, diff can be used to compare binary files, typically with the [-q option](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) to suppress the actual printing of differences, which rarely makes sense for binary files. You can also use [md5](http://linux.die.net/man/3/md5) or [cmp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp) if you have them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions :) but i'm facing another problem.. the code works perfectly when i tried to transfer an image of size 4.3kb..but it refuses to transfer an audio file of 5.7 mb :( pls help! do i need to convert data into byte and then transfer them?